# How to redirect to a new link from a POST endpoint in express?

Tags: reactjs, express, post, redirect, rest

I am using react in frontend and express for the backend.
I have a problem with redirecting from a POST endpoint in express app to a link in my react app.

**More Explanation**: I am integrating with a payment service and after the transaction happened on the third-party website, the service will send me a POST request with the transaction status and it will redirect the user to that endpoint too.
So I am planning to receive the transaction status in express and redirect the user back to my react app in frontend.

**Note** : redirect() function didn't work for me

```
// The route for recieving payment response
    app.get("/payment/response", (req, res) => {
      try {
        // receiving the transaction body in here and
        // redirecting the user to my react website 
        // The below codes are not working
        // return res.status(200).json({
        //   success: true,
        //   redirectUrl: "http://localhost:2200/user",
        // });
        // res.status(301).redirect("https://www.google.com");
        // return res.status(200).json({
        //   success: true,
        //   redirectUrl: "",
        // });
      } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json("Something went wrong");
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!!!

Apparently, **CORS** was the issue.
The react and express app is running on different ports and after allowing **CORS** redirect problem is solved.

In development, the CORS error was not showing up and that made the process complicated but once the app was deployed, the redirect started working.